# How can I remove .NET SDK completely?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, sdk, uninstallation

In the process of installation of Unity and VS code, I installed .NET SDK x64 unnecessarily.

How do I remove it safely? I'm using MacBook Pro(13-inch, M1, 2020).

I downloaded from this site : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

Answer (score 0):

You have several options available to you. You can safely remove the SDK as you would any ordinary program, but Microsoft has specific instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?pivots=os-macos) to help you remove an SDK from mac OS. Bear in mind if you installed a runtime for the unnecessary SDK you will also need to remove that separately. The docs contain links and further instructions as well.

Edit:

I recommend using the .Net Uninstall Tool that is linked in MS' docs I linked to above. It is the easiest and completely thorough.